# How to change the background of an DMG Software License Agreement dialog?

Tags: macos, finder, dmg

When I create my own dmg-images, I always attach a software license agreement to them. When I opened the flattened image, I always got the Jaguar "X" in the background of the agreement dialog, where I have to confirm to the SLA before the image will be mounted. I believe that since Lion, apple removed that, so the eula-dialog is clean.

[image: [Please upload pictures of what you are seeing here]]

Is it possible to set a custom image into the SLA-Dialog on Lion or later OS X?

Comment: As this has a certain software development flavor (which is offtopic here) and you've already asked the question on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926559/change-the-background-image-of-dmg-sla), let's close it FOR NOW. Feel free to request a reopen in a few days if you don't get an answer on SO.

Comment: I'm going to disagree with this and let's have a question on Meta to discuss this. Specifically, system admin make custom DMG all the time to distribute their packages. (and I'm not sure if this is a .dmg issue or a dev tools issue, so I'll tilt towards "let it ride" side of things until I'm certain. Consultants, managers, technical writers all can do this - it's not really a code level question as much as how does OS X render a DMG when opened in Finder. Let's see if we can get an answer here rather then sending it to SO because it was asked by a programmer instead of someone that's a user.

Comment: A few months have passed. Did you ever find an answer? Maybe you should answer your own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that it is not possible – the "X" in the background is OS specific.
The last macOS version that showed it on mounting the image was Snow Leopard. All versions of macOS that followed after that did not use it anymore.

However, you could use an image within the Textfield, since it represents an RTF-File Format.

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to create DMGs and play with every option is to use the popular [DropDMG](http://c-command.com/dropdmg/) from Michael Tsai. It's not free, but he has great support and it's very communicative and there's a trial version.

<sub>*Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with Michael Tsai, but I've known him (and his products) for a long time now, when I started using [SpamSieve](http://c-command.com/spamsieve/) (another of his great products).*</sub>

Comment: I've tried DropDMG already, and it seems to be a very handy tool, especially for creating license agreements. Unfortunately it can't do what I am looking for...

Comment: Try talking with the Author, he may give you some more insight about it. He usually replies to his email ;)